# Dagger2 custom scopes and destroy component

Tags: android, dagger-2

As I understand it, when scoping components and modules, instances that are (@)provided will live as long as the components that expose them exist.

More concretely, in the case of an @User scoped component, we can drop the @provided objects (provided by the modules) that are populated with user specific data when a user logs out. When a new user logs in, we should create a new Dagger component, that in turns exposes objects that will be populated with that (newly logged in) user specific data. These objects will in turn be kept alive as long as the component is not destroyed on log out.

My question is simply, how do we destroy a (sub)component on log out?
Is it sufficient that we just set the component to null so that it can be garbage collected, and create a new component manually through the builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to clean up after yourself. Destroying the component does not destroy its scoped objects and if you keep a reference to a scoped object longer than the components lifecycle it is usually a good source for memory leaks.

---

Dagger will inject or construct your objects, but what you do with those objects is entirely up to you. If you were to save a `User` object obtained from your `UserComponent` in a static variable it would obviously still be available after the component was garbage collected.

To prevent issues like this it is a good idea to *not* make use of static variables and to watch out when you hand short-living objects to longer-living ones.

If you have some UserScoped object it is not a good idea to reference it in your `Application`, unless you remove the reference along with your component when a user logs out. The easiest approach would be to receate every fragment, service, and activity that had access to the user scoped component, and clean up your Application / Singleton that held the component.

If you do not "leak" any shorter lived objects to longer lived ones the garbage collector will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a reference to component, object graph belong to that component exist in memory.

For login scoped component, as long as user is logged-in, keep a reference to the component so that dependency  injection can be done during user session.

You don't need to keep reference to component if dependencies are injected only once, for example component belong to specific android activity.